# How to define a custom li element with respect to accessability requirements?

Tags: html, accessibility, web-component

I would like to build my own list item as a **custom element**:

```html
<ul>
  <my-li><!-- Advanced stuff in shadow dom will be rendered here --></my-li>
</ul>
```

However, within an ul tag, only the following elements are allowed (li, script, template). What would be the right approach here?

1.) Definition of an aria-role on the custom element?

```html
<ul>
  <my-li aria-role="listitem"><!-- Advanced stuff in shadow dom will be rendered here --></my-li>
</ul>
```

2. Using the li tag inside the shadow-dom?

```html
<ul>
  <my-li><!-- Advanced stuff in shadow dom will be rendered within a li-tag here --></my-li>
</ul>
```

3. Something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do something else, as your two first are both invalid HTML.
You have several options, from best to worst:

Option 1:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <your-custom-element/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Option 2:
Manage the whole `<ul>` within the shadow DOM of your custom element, or put the `<ul>` as the root of it.

Option 3, which you should prefer avoid.

```
<div role="list">
  <your-custom-element role="list-item"/>
</div>

The best would be my option 1. It works because you can put anything you like inside `<li>`.

You should avoid my option 3 if you can, for several reasons:

- Avoid using ARIA unless it's really necessary
- No ARIA is better than bad ARIA
- It's not very clear if specifying the role on a custom element will work as expected, or if you have to report it yourself to the top element of your shadow DOM. It depends on what the browser / accessibility tree pass to assistive tools, and, as far as I know, it isn't very well defined, since custom elements are pretty new
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 3)

```
<div role="list">
    <my-li role="listitem"></my-li>
</div>
```

It cannot be 1) or 2) since both violate the HTML specs.

With 3) HTML specs and a11y demands are fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that if you implement a custom component (with custom visual bullet points), those graphic components (the bullet points) need to follow contrast requirements of [WCAG 1.4.11](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/non-text-contrast.html) (at least 3:1 contrast) if they are the only way in which the visual user can identify that it is a list.